# Draw a number of rectangles from list of coordinates

Tags: graphics, core-language

I'm new to Mathematica and this is also my first post here. Now for the question:

I try to let Mathematica draw a number of rectangles from lists of coordinates. Unfortunately it only works when I assign values to variables directly (for example: `a=3`) but not with lists.

Mathematica tells me that the coordinates have to be pairs of numbers (what they are, as far as I understand, because they are in the format `{x,y}`).

I imagine something like this:

```
min = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Blue}], White,Table[Rectangle[min, {5,5}]]}]
```

Which I hope should draw three rectangles with different starting points and the same endpoint. This is just chosen as a simple example, later start- and endpoint shall be given via lists.

I've tried  few different approaches:

**1.** A list with coordinates ("min" mentioned earlier) --> error message (see above)

**2.** Two lists to split x- and y-coordinate --> error message (see above)

**3.** Using functions to calculate the coordinates (just as a test), which looks like this:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Blue}], White, 
  Table[Rectangle[{a + 1, a + 2}, {5, 5}], {a, 2}]}] --> works
```

**4.** Using a list for iteration, basically I've changed the {a,2} above to {a,minc} with minc beeing minc={{1},{2}} --> error message (see above)

**5.** Using a list for iteration but try to pick it's elements, leading to {a,Part[minc]} --> error message (see above)

**6.** Assigned coordiantes to variables directly and used this variables (for example: a=1, b=2, Rectangle[{a,b},{5,5}]) --> works

So, how do I manage to read in coordinates from lists for this application?

Comment: Look up `Map[]` and `MapThread[]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @Guess who it is: Thank you for the hint! I looked it up but I couldn't make it work. I believe I did not really understand the syntax and ended up with this: Map[Graphics[Rectangle[{#}, {5, 5}]] & /@ max]. But I guess it is the same problem like m_goldberg pointed out (which works...).

@ bbgodfrey: Thank you, I'll try my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple error. You must give a second argument to `Table` which gives the interation specifications.

```
min = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Blue}], White, Table[Rectangle[m, {5, 5}], {m, min}]}]
```

[image: rects]

Comment: Thank you for your help, this really was easy. Now I feel like a fool...

Comment: @Gaston. Don't feel bad, making errors like this one is part of the learning process. I been using _Mathematica_ for 18 years and I still make similar mistakes sometimes. What experience brings is the ability to recognize such mistakes quickly.